# Spring Boot with the usage of jpaStreamer $ issue - Cannot resolve symbol 'User$'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpastreamer

I tried to implement an example of Spring Boot with the usage of `jpaStreamer`. I use `Intellij Idea` to handle with it. I have a problem in `jpaStreamer.stream`.

Here are the dependencies shown below

```
<jpastream.version>1.1.4</jpastream.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.speedment.jpastreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpastreamer-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jpastream.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.speedment.jpastreamer.integration.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jpastreamer-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>${jpastream.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the sample method of UserService shown below

```
public List<User> findAllForJpaStreamer() {
   return jpaStreamer.stream(User.class).
          sorted(User$.id).
          collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I get this error message shown below

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'User$'
```

Here is the screenshot shown below

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/jpastreamer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It caused by the version of `jpastream.version`. After I defined it as `3.0.3` in pom.xml, the problem disappeared.

```
<jpastream.version>3.0.3</jpastream.version>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading their documentation, and the gradle integration, I think you are simply lacking the annotation processor:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.speedment.jpastreamer:jpastreamer-core:version"
    annotationProcessor "com.speedment.jpastreamer:fieldgenerator-standard:version"
}
```

To fix your problem, you probably just need to add an annotation processor: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>com.speedment.jpastreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>fieldgenerator-standard</artifactId>
        <version>${jpastream.version}</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You may also, if it works, create a [pull request](https://github.com/speedment/jpa-streamer#maven) to fix the README.

Comment: I wanted to share the repo with you. I already defined JPAstreamer dependency in pom.xml with its plugin but I cannot create class under `annotations`. Where is the problem?

Comment: I am not an user of jpastreamer. But `User$` seems like generated code to me, pretty much like `User_` with Hibernate JPA Annotation processor, hence my reply.

Comment: There: I fixed the version issue.